# Cryptic template template parameter error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, types, typename

I'm trying to create a function that gets the keys from a `std::map` or an `std::unordered_map`. I could use a simple overload, but first I'd love to know what's wrong with this code.

```
template<typename K, typename V, template<typename, typename> class TContainer>  
std::vector<K> getKeys(const TContainer<K, V>& mMap)
{
    std::vector<K> result;
    for(const auto& itr(std::begin(mMap)); itr != std::end(mMap); ++itr) result.push_back(itr->first);
    return result;
}
```

When calling it with an `std::unordered_map`, even specifying *all* template typenames manually, clang++ 3.4 says:

> template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` are not in fact templates with two parameters.  They are:

```
namespace std {
    template <class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>,
              class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key, T>>>
    class map;

    template <class Key, class T, class Hash = hash<Key>,
              class Pred = equal_to<Key>,
              class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key, T>>>
    class unordered_map;
}
```

Here's something similar that does work:

```
template <typename K, typename... TArgs, template<typename...> class TContainer>
std::vector<K> getKeys(const TContainer<K, TArgs...>& mMap)
{
    std::vector<K> result;
    for (auto&& p : mMap)
        result.push_back(p.first);
    return result;
}
```

The version I would prefer:

```
template <typename Container>
auto getKeys2(const Container& mMap) -> std::vector<typename Container::key_type>
{
    std::vector<typename Container::key_type> result;
    for (auto&& p : mMap)
        result.push_back(p.first);
    return result;
}
```

A demo program using both functions: http://ideone.com/PCkcu6

Comment: Oh, I feel so stupid now. Is there a way to match both `map` and `unordered_map` without creating two different overloads? The number of template parameters differs.

Comment: Edited with a possible "fix".  But it would probably be better to somehow use `decltype(mMap)::key_type`.

Comment: Came up with the same fix minutes before you posted it, hehe. Thanks for everything!

Comment: Great improvement in my opinion. I changed the `auto` to `const auto&` and implemented it in my library.

Comment: This answer works perfectly. At Bloomberg I must have found another solution but don't remember it. The problem stems from wanting underneath to actually store the map with a decorated mapped_type so not exactly the one the user provides.