# Substitution failure for template template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I want a helper function to instantiate a class for me. Currently it cannot compile in clang (though it compiles work in gcc), but I need it to work in clang as well. Currently I'm using `clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2`.

I'm not sure why it's failing, since gcc is able to detect the type. I tried doing stuff from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220714/cryptic-template-template-parameter-error) and playing around with it for a while but I keep running into a wall. MCVE available, or you can try it on [coliru here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f24375d3dc8809ff):

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, template <typename> typename Container>
struct SomeClass {
    SomeClass(const Container<T>& c) {
    }
};

template <typename T, template <typename> typename C>
inline auto make_some_class(const C<T>& container) {
    return SomeClass<T, C>(container);
}

int main() {
    vector<int> ints;

    auto stuff = make_some_class(ints);  
}
```

> main.cpp:19:18: error: no matching function for call to 'make_some_class'
>
> ```
>    auto stuff = make_some_class(ints);  
>
>                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> main.cpp:12:13: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = int]: template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter
>
> ```
> inline auto make_some_class(const C<T>& container) {
>
>             ^
> ```
>
> 1 error generated.

Comment: This looks like non-deducible context, even if we temporarily ignore the basic fact that `std::vector` has two template parameters, not one, and will not match `template<typename> typename Container` in the first place.

Comment: I expect you are using Clang and it would work if you add a compilation flag `-frelaxed-template-template-args`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It is not a non-deducible context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suggestion: try with

```
#include <vector>

template <template <typename...> typename Container, typename ... Ts>
struct SomeClass {
    SomeClass(const Container<Ts...>& c) {
    }
};

template <template <typename...> typename C, typename ... Ts>
inline auto make_some_class(const C<Ts...>& container) {
    return SomeClass<C, Ts...>(container);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> ints;

    auto stuff = make_some_class(ints);  
}
```

I mean... I suppose the problem is that `std::vector` isn't a container that receive **one** type template parameter; it's a container that receive **two** type template parameter (the second one with a default type: `std::allocator<T>` where `T` is the first one).

So the suggestion is: make `SomeClass` more flexible and able to receive a container with an variadic list of template types of arguments

```
template <typename...> typename Container
```

**and** the corresponding list of template types

```
typename ... Ts
```

If you want a variadic list of arguments (`Ts...`) you need it in last position so you have to switch the position of `Container` and `T` (now `Ts...`): before `Container` and after the variadic list `Ts...`

```
template <template <typename...> typename Container, typename ... Ts>
struct SomeClass {
    SomeClass(const Container<Ts...>& c) {
    }
};
```

Not strictly required but, for uniformity, I suggest to rewrite `make_some_class()` in the same way (and, obviously, pass `C` before `Ts...` in the template parameters list).

```
template <template <typename...> typename C, typename ... Ts>
inline auto make_some_class(const C<Ts...>& container) {
    return SomeClass<C, Ts...>(container);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's reduce this to just:

```
template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
void foo(C<T> const&) { }

std::vector<int> v;
foo(v);
```

You'll find that gcc compiles that but clang does not. The reasons for both are interesting.

First, recall that `std::vector` is a class template that takes *two* template parameters:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class vector { ... };
```

Why does gcc think that matches `template <typename> class C` - a template which has only *one* template parameter? Because the rules changed as a result of [P0522R0](https://wg21.link/p0522r0). And it makes sense - we can use `vector` as if it had one type parameter in normal code, so it should be able to match such a template parameter.

Now, why does clang think that `vector` *doesn't* match? Because they *explicitly* are choosing to not adopt this rule. From [their docs](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html):

> (10): Despite being the resolution to a Defect Report, this feature is disabled by default in all language versions, and can be enabled explicitly with the flag `-frelaxed-template-template-args` in Clang 4 onwards. The change to the standard lacks a corresponding change for template partial ordering, resulting in ambiguity errors for reasonable and previously-valid code. This issue is expected to be rectified soon.

That is, it might [break code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47293162/2069064).

---

Of course you might just want to know how to fix it. Just change the declaration of the template template parameter `C`:

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T>
void foo(C<T> const&) { }

std::vector<int> v;
foo(v); // ok in both gcc and clang
```

Comment: I don't think omitting the variadic template params `Ts...` as in the accepted answer works on MSVC (but does on Clang).

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested in comment and max66, `std::vector` has two template parameters, the `value_type` and `allocator_type`.
Before C++17, we must explicitly write both parameters as template template parameters in this case as follows and this would also work in C++17:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jW9CXn9oZVhJqZAp)

```
template <typename T, template <typename V, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>> typename Container>
struct SomeClass {
    SomeClass(const Container<T>& c) {
    }
};

template <typename T, template <typename V, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>> typename C>
inline auto make_some_class(const C<T>& container) {
    return SomeClass<T, C>(container);
}
```

---

BTW, since C++17, ["Matching template template parameters to compatible arguments" [`P0522R0`]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html) is accepted and your code is right if you are using C++17.
But [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) still disable this new feature at default and the compilation flag `-frelaxed-template-template-args` enables this feature.

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VOqpmANRtfPjPidg)

Comment: The reason clang disables this feature by default would improve this answer.